# Arabic text not display proper, php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 queries in same page, one display arabic text properly, but other one not, it display like `Ø³ÙŠØ¯Ø© Ø³Ø§Ø¦Ù‚`

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

this line is included, it works in local host, but not in server

Comment: You got the page charset correct. Now you need to assert database content, schema, and connection settings. (In particular if it's not working only on one server.)

Comment: but one query retrive and print properly in same page

Comment: Then there's a fiddy-fiddy chance that it's already misencoded in the database. (Which is impossible to guess without sufficient details. See the duplicate. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31904202/edit) with all conditions listed and checked. Present a combined text/hexdump of DB contents, etc.)